# Правильное написание слова(5)

Tags: грамотная-речь

Как пишется сокращённое от выражения "ничего себе" слово "ничёсе"? "Ничё се" или "ничёсе".

Comment: Что значит "(5)"?

Comment: "5" — это порядковый номер. Уже есть несколько вопросов с такой шапкой.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Оно пишется **вместе**: *ничёсе*.
[https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/dic_synonims/346157/ничёсе](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/dic_synonims/346157/%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%87%D1%91%D1%81%D0%B5)